# How to perform Left-Factoring on a Grammar, make it LL(1)

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science, left-recursion

This is the grammar I have that is not left recursive. I have to make it LL(1). How do I go about doing this?

```
S -> Exp eof
Exp -> Term Exp2
Exp2 -> + Term Exp2 | - Term Exp2| e 
Term -> Factor Term2
Term2 ->  * Factor Term2 | / Factor Term2 | e 
Factor -> id | num | Fncall | Aref | (Exp)
Fncall -> id (Arguments)
Aref -> id [Indices]
Arguments -> Exp | Exp, Arguments
Incides -> Exp | Exp, Indices
```

Comment: I don't really understand how LL(1) works or what it means, so I'm kinda stuck

Comment: How is it that you have to do this work, but you don't understand the work you have to do?

Comment: It wasn't made clear in our practical so I've been left to figure it out myself